# how can I solve "Using the Impeller rendering backend." error?

Tags: flutter, dart

After upgrading flutter version to 3.13.0 I get such an error. "[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(37)] Using the Impeller rendering backend."

I see splash screen for a second.All of sudden it crashes.

```
<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
  <false />
```

I used this in info.plist .Unfortunately it did not help

Comment: "Using the Impeller rendering backend." is not an error. Whatever crashes your app, it's something different.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**iOS**

Flutter enables Impeller by default on iOS.

To disable Impeller on iOS when debugging, pass `--no-enable-impeller` to the `flutter run` command.

```
flutter run --no-enable-impeller
```

To disable Impeller on iOS when deploying your app, add the following tags under the top-level  tag in your app’s `Info.plist` file.

```
<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
<false />
```

The team continues to improve macOS support. If you encounter performance or fidelity issues with Impeller on macOS, file an issue in the
[GitHub tracker](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose). Prefix the issue title with [Impeller] and include a small reproducible test case.

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/impeller

Comment: Not at all sir.

Comment: is it recommended to disable impeller when deploying?

Comment: Didn't solve my issue

Comment: Didn't work for me too

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this problem by closing the **Xcode Simulator**.

Don't have it open when you want to run on the device.